# Booking date < = 30 days from the departure date. how we can achieve this requirement using DATEADD function In marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I used for dateadd function for above requirement i got the data in my dataextension. Could please give me any suggestion for achieve this requirement.
  I tried following code for below requirement could please review my code.

```
   Select Id, departure_date__c,Booking_date__c from Reservation_DE 
   where Booking_date__c <=DATEADD(day, +30,departure_date__c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted something similar - wanted to add people exactly 28 days before they go to an event. Had to expand the DateAdd a bit to get the date component, and this works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DE_NAME
WHERE ([arrivalDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, 30, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
```

optional...

```
SELECT * 
FROM DE_NAME
WHERE ([arrivalDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, 30, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) 
AND [arrivalDate] < DATEADD(DAY, 31, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost there . Your code will return information 30 days after the `departure_date__c`. Change `+30` to `-30`.

```
SELECT Id
, departure_date__c
,Booking_date__c 
FROM Reservation_DE 
WHERE Booking_date__c <=DATEADD(day, -30,departure_date__c)
```

Reference:

- [Official DateAdd Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)

Comment: Thank you for providing information  and official document.